# Signification de « Inscrire noir sur blanc »

Tags: sens, expressions, étymologie

Source : https://www.europe1.fr/politique/outrage-sexiste-inscrire-noir-sur-blanc-quil-est-interdit-dintimider-des-femmes-dans-lespace-public-3504191

> **Inscrire noir sur blanc** qu'il est interdit d'intimider des femmes dans l'espace public.

Vu aussi dans un dossier de candidature (poste d'enseignant-chercheur) :

> Ce souhait qui m’anime, je l'**inscris noir sur blanc** dans ce document.

1. Que veut dire la tournure *inscrire noir sur blanc* dans ce contexte ?
2. Quelle est son étymologie ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On ne trouve dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/noir) que l'expression « mettre les choses noir sur blanc ».

Dans le Littré se trouve seulement une variante ;

> Familièrement. Mettre du noir sur du blanc, écrire, composer. ([Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/noir))

L'expression « [noir sur blanc](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noir+sur+blanc%2Cles+choses+noir+sur+blanc&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnoir%20sur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20choses%20noir%20sur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnoir%20sur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20choses%20noir%20sur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0) » commence à se trouver au moins au début du 19<sup>e</sup>, mais « mettre les choses noir sur blanc » est rare.

On trouve cependant depuis le début du 20<sup>e</sup> « mettre noir sur blanc ». ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mettre+noir+sur+blanc&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmettre%20noir%20sur%20blanc%3B%2Cc0))

Le dictionnaire de l'Académie est plus informatif ([D. Ac.](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/noir?page=1));

> Loc. adv. Noir sur blanc, en toutes lettres, avec netteté, sans ambiguïté. Mettre noir sur blanc, mettre par écrit, indiquer clairement par un document. Il a mis ses idées noir sur blanc. Cette clause est stipulée noir sur blanc.

L'origine est sans aucun doute l'idée du noir de l'encre sur le blanc du papier, mais je ne dispose pas d'information quant aux circonstances de la création de cette expression.

Bien que ce ne soit pas spécifiquement mentionné dans les dictionnaires, il faudrait considérer qu'il existe deux sens de l'expression :

- par écrit,
- sans ambiguïté, clairement, sans paraphrases.

En conséquence, lorsque l'on trouve ou que l'on entend des phrases telles que  « C'est écrit noir sur blanc dans tel et tel écrit. » il faut comprendre « écrit sans détours, clairement » (le sens « 2 » et non le « 1 »).

exemple

- C'est noir sur blanc dans leur règlement. (*c'est écrit dans leur règlement.*)

Answer (score 2):

Je pencherais pour une origine germanique (All. : *Schwarz auf weiß* / Néerl. : *Zwart op wit*).

On trouve dans Faust :

> *Denn, was man **schwarz auf weiß besitzt**,
>
> Kann man getrost nach Hause tragen.*
> Goethe, *Faust*, 1808

que Gérard de Nerval traduit en 1828 :

> quand on a **mis du noir sur du blanc**,
> on rentre chez soi tout-à-fait soulagé.

Alors qu'Albert Strapfer traduit la même année :

> quand on rentre chez soi avec **du noir sur du blanc**,
> on tient déjà quelque chose

L'expression a déjà ici sa signification moderne, **rapporter par écrit quelque chose pour qu'il y en ait une trace concrète, incontestable, qui ne soit pas sujette aux aléas de la mémoire**.

L'expression existait déjà en allemand car on la trouve dans ce dictionnaire allemand-français de 1782:

[image]

L'expression n'est en revanche pas encore répandue en France puisque bien qu'on la retrouve dans la traduction des *Mémoires et voyages du prince Puckler Muskau* de 1833 :

[image]

elle y renvoie à cette note de bas de page qui en explique le sens :

[image]

D'autre part, dans l'ouvrage *Les "on dit" et les "on ne dit pas" ou les Plaintes de la muse française*, 1860, de Georges Verenet, qui indique en préambule *ce petit ouvrage a pour but essentiel de recueillir les expressions vicieuses, particulières à la Hollande et pour la plupart contractées sur les bancs poudreux de l'école,* on trouve la recommandation suivante :

[image]
[image]

Comment: C'est dans [Ac.6](http://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A6N0272) (1835) qui le dit familier, noté au [FEW](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/index.php/page/lire/e/179562), donc on peut penser que ça vient avant, mais c'est pas dans Ac.5 (1798 ; évidemment ça ne signifie pas la non-existence auparavant, pour plein de raisons qu'on pourrait imaginer.). Je comprends pas que le DHLF ne dise rien ni à _blanc_, ni à _noir_ ni à _mettre_ mais il dit 1761 pour la typographie, le blanc, ce qui est laissé vide...

Answer (score 1):

You ask: "Quelle est son étymologie?"

It may be a calque from English. Google can find "put/have it down in black and white" in English at the beginning of the 19th century, whereas "inscrit noir sur blanc" only goes back to the beginning of the 20th.

See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inscrit+noir+sur+blanc%2Cdown+in+black+and+white%3Aeng_2019%2C+%C3%A9crit+noir+sur+blanc&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3).

Peut-être c'est un calque de l'anglais. Google trouve "put/have it down in black and white" en anglais au début du 19<sup>e</sup> siècle, alors que "inscrit noir sur blanc" ne se trouve qu'au début du 20<sup>e</sup>.